# Razor syntax: Trouble figuring out nested statements and variable scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm having trouble figuring out Razor syntax and how variable scope works. I'm new to C# in general as well as Razor syntax.  Here is some code I created parallel what I'm looking to do, just a bit simpler.

I have an array represented by `ViewBag.Photos` that I want to iterate though to display in my UI code.  However, for the first photo, I need to add a distinctive secondary class named `active` for my UI code (using a jquery plugin) to display properly since it needs to know what the first photo is.

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to accomplish it?

```
<div class="foo">
    @{int i = 1;}
    @foreach (var photo in ViewBag.Photos) 
    {
        if (i == 1) { 
            <div class="item active">
        } 
        else {
            <div class="item">
        }
        <img src="@photo" alt="@ViewBag.SomeVar">
        <div class="bar">
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        @{i++};
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="foo">
    @{
          int i = 1;
          @foreach (var photo in ViewBag.Photos) 
          {
             if (i++ == 1) { 
               <div class="item active">
             } 
             else {
               < div class="item">
             }
             <img src="@photo" alt="@ViewBag.SomeVar">
             <div class="bar">
                <p>Test</p>
             </div>
             </div>

       }
    }
</div>
```

or

```
    <div class="foo">
    @{
          int i = 1;
          var className = "item";
          @foreach (var photo in ViewBag.Photos) 
          {
             className = i++ == 1 ? "item active" : "item";
             <div class="@className">
                   <img src="@photo" alt="@ViewBag.SomeVar">
                   <div class="bar">
                       <p>Test</p>
                  </div>
             </div>

       }
    }
</div>
```

Comment: This is a more direct answer to my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use a for statement, rather than a foreach.

```
<div class="foo"> 
@for(int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Photos.Count; i++)  
{ 
    <div class="@((i == 0) ? "item active" : "item")">
        <img src="@ViewBag.Photos[i].Photo" alt="@ViewBag.Photos[i].AltText"> 
        <div class="bar"> 
            <p>Test</p> 
        </div> 
    </div> 
} 
</div>
```

I assume Photos is an array of some class that wraps both the photo and alt text.  If not, you would do something like this:

```
<img src="@ViewBag.Photos[i]" alt="@ViewBag.AltText[i]">
```

You really should be using a View Model, however.  You would probably also do better using a DisplayTemplate as well.  But that should get you started.

UPDATE:  I would write the code as the above using the conditional operator.  I think it's easier to read, and less confusing.

Comment: @Mystere Man: Can you elaborate on how I'd use a View Model for this? I have a model that already gets all the Photos and my Controller is populating the ViewBag based on it.

Comment: @Indeed.  I was actually changing that when yo wrote the comment.

Comment: @TMC - It's hard to elaborate because I don't know what the rest of your view looks like.  But typically you would use `@model` at the top of your View and specify a model type, that model type would include the Photos array.

Comment: Oddly, I'm getting an error `Parser Error Message: The for block is missing a closing "}" character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters are being interpreted as markup.` and it's highlighting this line `@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.PhotosByUser.Count; i++)`.  There definitely opening and close `{}` after the for loop. This is the only razor syntax block in the entire file.

Comment: @TMC - Razor can't always identify the correct blocks, but it does a pretty good job most of the time.  You may have to add an `@` before the second if statement.

Comment: @MystereMan: Still no dice. Tried adding a `@` in front of the second if statement but still same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7596/discussion-between-tmc-and-mystere-man)